# Forcibly remove alpha testers from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to forcibly remove alpha testers from my Google Play Alpha test program.

So far I've only found a way for users to remove themselves by clicking on the link once they're already enrolled.

Does anyone know how force users out of an alpha test group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the *Open Alpha Test* program. I needed to click *Switch to another type of alpha testing* and choose *Closed Alpha Test*.

From there I could whitelist users I wanted to be in the program. Any users from my previous Open Alpha Test were enrolled as soon as I whitelisted then, so they don't have to visit the opt-in page again, which is nice.